# partition blocks of a 2D array with memcpy

Tags: arrays, c, memcpy

I saw several questions on memcpy but none seem to answer my question
I want to copy a block of the array (left-up, then right-up, then left-bottom, right-bottom)
I tried for left up but can't get it to work...

(* Edit removed old code *)

```
initial matrix:
{{1,2,39,4},
 {4,5,6,4},
 {7,8,9,4},
 {10,12,30,40}
};
```

I want to retrieve in this example a 2x2 matrix containing:

| 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 |

Any way to achieve this?

Edit: thanks to @Adrian Mole's comment, I now know 1 single memcpy can't handle this. Any idea on how to handle this in a generic way (that depends on the size of n)? I modified my code as follows:

```
void partition2 (int ** mat, int ** A, int sub_mtrx_size){
    int i,j, ioff, joff;
    // A TOP-lEFT only for now, worry about other blocks B,C,D later
    ioff= 0 * sub_mtrx_size;
    joff= 0 * sub_mtrx_size;
    printf( "%d %d\n" ,ioff,joff);
    for (i = 0; i < sub_mtrx_size; i++) {
        memcpy( A[i] , mat[i+ioff],sub_mtrx_size );

        for (j = 0; j < sub_mtrx_size; j++) {
            // A[i][j] =mat[i+ioff][j+joff];  // this works, but not with 1 single memcpy
            printf("%3d ", mat[i+ioff][j+joff]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

int main() {
const int n = 4;

int ** mat =  malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
int ** C11 =  malloc(sizeof(int*) * n/2);
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    mat[k] =  malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    if ( k < n/2){
        C11[k] =  malloc(sizeof(int) * (n/2));
    }
    
}
printf("aaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n");
init(mat,n,n);
// init puts {{1,2,39,4},{4,5,6,4},{7,8,9,4},{10,12,30,40}};
int sub_mtrx_size= n/2;
partition2(mat,C11,sub_mtrx_size );
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // int* currentIntPtr = mat[i];
        free(mat[i]);
        if ( i < n/2){
            free(C11[i]);
        }
    }
    free (mat);
    free (C11);
return 0;
}
```

with memcpy here I get the first column only...

Thanks

Comment: You simply can't copy array elements like this with a single `memcpy`, because your desired `C11` elements aren't stored *contiguously* in `src`.

Comment: I had a doubt about this... any suggestion on how to partition a matrix the way I need it then?

Comment: Yes - write a function that copies the relevant elements from source to destination. How that operates will depend on a number of things: array sizes, complexity, &c. In your case of a 2x2 destination, simply assigning each element is probably the most efficient way.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks! I edited my code thanks to your tip. a bit closer but can't get it to work with 1 memcpy per row, I can do it naively with 1 element at a time with [i][j]. Something wrong with my logic?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it:

here is a partition function that extracts 4 blocks (A,B,C,D) out of the initial matrix `mat` It is only tested and supposed to work for sizes of power 2.

```
void partition2 (int ** mat, int ** A,int ** B,int ** C,int ** D, int sub_mtrx_size){
    int i,j, ioff, joff;
    // A TOP-lEFT
    ioff= 0 * sub_mtrx_size;
    joff= 0 * sub_mtrx_size;
    for (i = 0; i < sub_mtrx_size; i++) {
        memcpy( A[i] , mat[i+ioff], sub_mtrx_size* sizeof(**A) );

    }
    
    
    // B Bottom-left
    ioff= 1 * sub_mtrx_size;
    joff= 0 * sub_mtrx_size;
    for (i = 0; i < sub_mtrx_size; i++) {
        memcpy( B[i] , mat[i+ioff], sub_mtrx_size* sizeof(**A) );
    }


    // C TOP-right
    ioff= 0 * sub_mtrx_size;
    joff= 1 * sub_mtrx_size;
    for (i = 0; i < sub_mtrx_size; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<sub_mtrx_size ; j++){
            C[i][j] = mat[i+ioff][j+joff];
        }

    }

    
    // D BOTTOM-RIGHT
    ioff= 1 * sub_mtrx_size;
    joff= 1 * sub_mtrx_size;
    for (i = 0; i < sub_mtrx_size; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<sub_mtrx_size ; j++){
            D[i][j] = mat[i+ioff][j+joff];
        }
    
    }
    

}
```